# R returning a pair

Tags: r, list, return

In R I am trying to return a pair from a function where the first element in the pair is a vector and the second is a map. Here is the return statement:

```
returnList = list("kmeansVector" = kmV, "clustMap" = clustMap)
return(returnList)
```

Say in the console I set `li` to the return value of  this function. Then `li[1]` will give me all elements that are in `kmV`. What I want is to do `l[1][3]` which would give me the 3rd element originally in `kmV`but R tells me it is null:

```
> li[1][3]
$<NA>
NULL

> attributes(li[1])
$names
[1] "kmeansVector"
```

`kmV` is a 5 element vector of `kmeans` objects. So it appears that when the function returns the list every elemen in `kmV` gets concatenated together. How do I get the 3rd element that was originally in `kmV`

Comment: Try `li[[1]][3]`. I believe `li[1]` will return a list containing your vector, which will make `[3]` look for a third element in said list (returning `NULL` because none exists).

Comment: BlueMagister is exactly right. This has nothing to do with k-means or the concept of pair but everything to do with how lists are accessed. The "[" function returns a sub-list which has an impenetrable membrane around it that prevents access. To break through you need "[[".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has almost certainly been answered before on Stack Overflow, but I cannot find it. So here's a local answer:

As described by the help file of `` help(`[[`) ``, under **Recursive (list-like) objects**:

> Indexing by [ is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of the
>   specified element(s).
>
> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference
>   is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is
>   equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching
>   behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

Using `[` on a list returns a list, because `[` can grab multiple elements in the list. Using `[[` will return the element of that list.

Here's an example that should help explain. Below, `a` is a list of two elements.

```
> a <- list(1:4,letters[24:26])
> a
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] "x" "y" "z"

> a[1:2]
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] "x" "y" "z"

> a[1] #returns a list of length 1 containing the first element
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

> a[[1]] #returns the first element
[1] 1 2 3 4

> a[[1:2]] #equivalent to a[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2
```